# Finding similar pairs of data using SQL

Tags: sql, join

I have written the following Query

**Sample Query**

```
USE SampleDB
SELECT Sec.SecurityID, Port.PortfolioCode, Sec.SymbolNameSpace, Sec.Symbol, 
    PT.TradeAmount, PT.tradedate, PT.settledate, PT.PostDate, PT.TransactionCode, 
    PT.SecurityID1
FROM AdvApp.vPortfolioTransaction PT
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    AdvApp.vPortfolio PORT
    ON Port.PortfolioID = PT.PortfolioID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    AdvApp.vSecurity Sec
    ON Sec.SecurityID = PT.SecurityID1
WHERE Sec.SecurityID = 4678 or Sec.SecurityID = 6
ORDER BY PT.TradeAmount
```

**Desired Result Set**

```
SecurityID  PortfolioCode   SymbolNameSpace Symbol  TradeAmount tradedate   settledate  PostDate    TransactionCode SecurityID1
4678    pendingtest caus    pending  368,456.00     5/21/2013   NULL    5/21/2013   lo  4678
6   pendingtest caus    cash     368,456.15     5/22/2013   NULL    5/23/2013   lo  6
4678    pendingtest caus    pending  7,800.00   4/17/2013   NULL    5/21/2013   lo  4678
6   pendingtest caus    cash     7,801.00   4/23/2013   NULL    5/23/2013   lo  6
```

**Sample Actual Result Set**

```
SecurityID  PortfolioCode   SymbolNameSpace Symbol  TradeAmount tradedate   settledate  PostDate    TransactionCode SecurityID1
6   pendingtest caus    cash     240,453.70     7/16/2010   NULL    7/19/2010   lo  6
6   pendingtest caus    cash     249,562.32     1/19/2012   1/19/2012   1/20/2012   dp  6
6   pendingtest caus    cash     368,456.15     5/22/2013   NULL    5/23/2013   lo  6
6   pendingtest caus    cash     250,000.00     12/1/2003   NULL    12/1/2003   lo  6
6   pendingtest caus    cash     250,321.13     11/15/2010  11/15/2010  11/16/2010  dp  6
6   pendingtest caus    cash     365,445.58     1/31/1999   NULL    3/26/1999   dp  6
4678    pendingtest caus    pending  368,456.00     5/21/2013   NULL    5/21/2013   lo  4678
4678    pendingtest caus    pending  7,800.00   4/17/2013   NULL    5/21/2013   lo  4678
6   pendingtest caus    cash     7,801.00   4/23/2013   NULL    5/23/2013   lo  6
```

The logic is I only want to see table rows where pairs of rows match tradeamounts within +/- 5. I also only want to see lines where the SecurityID1 value is a combination of 4678 and 6. The pair will always have one row being SecurityID1 4678 and the other row being SecurityID1 6.

I searched extensively for how to pair transactions but I can't find any examples of how I would allow similar values within a tolerance of +/- 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind having **both paired transactions on the same row in the results** rather than separate rows, then you could create each set as derived tables, named for example `a` & `b` below. Then [`CROSS JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) them like this...

```
SELECT 
a.SecurityID SecurityID_a, a.PortfolioCode PortfolioCode_a, a.SymbolNameSpace SymbolNameSpace_a, a.Symbol Symbol_a, a.TradeAmount TradeAmount_a, a.tradedate TradeDate_a, a.settledate SettleDate_a, a.PostDate PostDate_a, a.TransactionCode TransactionCode_a, a.SecurityID1 SecurityID1_a,
b.SecurityID SecurityID_b, b.PortfolioCode PortfolioCode_b, b.SymbolNameSpace SymbolNameSpace_b, b.Symbol Symbol_b, b.TradeAmount TradeAmount_b, b.tradedate TradeDate_b, b.settledate SettleDate_b, b.PostDate PostDate_b, b.TransactionCode TransactionCode_b, b.SecurityID1 SecurityID1_b 
FROM 
(
  SELECT Sec.SecurityID, Port.PortfolioCode, Sec.SymbolNameSpace, Sec.Symbol, PT.TradeAmount, PT.tradedate, PT.settledate, PT.PostDate, PT.TransactionCode, PT.SecurityID1
  FROM AdvApp.vPortfolioTransaction PT
  JOIN AdvApp.vSecurity Sec ON Sec.SecurityID = PT.SecurityID1
  LEFT JOIN AdvApp.vPortfolio PORT ON Port.PortfolioID = PT.PortfolioID
  WHERE Sec.SecurityID = 4678 
) a
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT Sec.SecurityID, Port.PortfolioCode, Sec.SymbolNameSpace, Sec.Symbol, PT.TradeAmount, PT.tradedate, PT.settledate, PT.PostDate, PT.TransactionCode, PT.SecurityID1
  FROM AdvApp.vPortfolioTransaction PT
  JOIN AdvApp.vSecurity Sec ON Sec.SecurityID = PT.SecurityID1
  LEFT JOIN AdvApp.vPortfolio PORT ON Port.PortfolioID = PT.PortfolioID
  WHERE Sec.SecurityID = 6 
) b 
WHERE ABS(a.TradeAmount - b.TradeAmount) <= 5
```

- [**`Click here to see it in action at SQL Fiddle`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c9f9/2)

Comment: Thanks this is very close but gives a bit too much information. The query does work better if I include AND a.PortfolioCode = b.PortfolioCode but this only shows one line of the pair. Ideally I'd like to see both lines.

Comment: Also the one line that does show is the line where Symbol_a = pending. I'd also like to see the line where the symbol = cash

Comment: Indeed after I add the And clause I get all the info on one line. How complex would it be to see it on two lines? (Ignore previous comment I didn't notice it was all appearing on one line.

Comment: I don't think you should add the `AND`. The data items returned are the same as your desired result, just the pairs are in one row rather than separate rows. It also seems more natural that way to me because you are not relying on ordering to view as pairs because they are side by side in the same row. You just use the column aliases to differentiate them.

Comment: If I don't include AND the result set is too large. There were many instances where the tradeamount was within the 5 tolerance but port a and port b were not the same so this gave false positives. Using AND gave only real positives. One work around is to include two separate queries. One selecting only the port a columns and the second using port b columns. I could then use these as two datasets in an SSRS report (my final goal) but if I could do it all in one query that would be nice.

Comment: Ah OK, I think I see. Can you explain again the problem after you added the `AND`? I added it to [`the sql fiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c9f9/3) but it didn't change the result, but then I only have 1 portfolio code. Perhaps you could tweak the the fiddle to illustrate the issue you have now.

Comment: With AND the result set is accurate but all on one line, however I'm actually starting to think using AND may work. The problem in the SQL Server query result pane is the results are all on one line, but in SSRS I could place the various fields where I want. I haven't started plugging around with an SSRS report yet but I think we can call this one resolved I will mark it as answered. The results in the fiddle are a bit different than out of the DB. I hadn't been aware the fiddle was even available.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No probs, glad you got close to your result. Not sure about marking as answered because I've not asked a question yet! But that question has been asked before: [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) ;) Yeh SQL Fiddle is a great tool, I only started using it myself the other day.